# AWS Opswork puppet does not get github code

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet, r10k

I've set up a new AWS Opswork puppetmaster

It is supposedly configured with a ssh key that should allow access to github

However, it doesn't and fails very early on in the configuration steps.  I would like to know if there are any configuration items I can check and/or how I might be able to get the puppetmaster to pull puppet code from github

I have my own puppet configuration files and custom modules for local use on a private repository on github

However, if I do a "puppet-access login --lifetime 180d" to set up the token and then try and get it to work...

```
# puppet-code deploy --dry-run
--dry-run implies --wait.
--dry-run implies --all.
Dry-run deploying all environments.
Errors while collecting a list of environments to deploy (exit code: 1).
ERROR    -> Unable to determine current branches for Git source 'puppet' (/etc/puppetlabs/code-staging/environments)
Original exception:
Invalid credential type
```

The path `/etc/puppetlabs/code-staging/environments` does not exist

The ssh key definitely works however

```
# ssh -i /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssh/id-control_repo.rsa -T git@github.com
Hi billybob22! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

And the ssh key is readable by pe-puppet

```
# su pe-puppet -s /bin/bash -c 'test -r /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssh/id-control_repo.rsa; echo $?'
0
# ls -l /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssh/id-control_repo.rsa
-r-------- 1 pe-puppet pe-puppet 3243 Dec 19 14:45 /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssh/id-control_repo.rsa
# ls -ld /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssh
dr-x------ 2 pe-puppet pe-puppet 4096 Dec  6 16:32 /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssh
```

I have tried using the github url in the form

```
"puppet_enterprise::profile::master::r10k_remote": "git@github.com:myorg/my-puppetrepos"
```

and also

```
"puppet_enterprise::profile::master::r10k_remote": "ssh://github.com/myorg/my-puppetrepos"
```

Both forms give identical results as outlined above

Not got much idea where to take it from here!  The docs (both Puppetlabs and AWS ) cover some problems but not this.  Just to repeat my question: what further diagnostics should I do to try and resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format for the repository location is

git@github.com:myorg/my-puppetrepos

I couldn't find any way of changing this value in an existing Opsworks puppetmaster so I just blew it away and started another one, giving the correct value at the start

I assume my problem was caused by giving the incorrect GitHub URL